# Error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before

Tags: c

I am trying to write code to build a stack, but I'm getting compilation errors which don't make sense to me. Here is my `stack.h`:

```
struct StackNode {

    void* previous;
    int   value;
};


struct Stack {

    StackNode* top;
};


Stack* new_stack () {

    StackNode stn = { NULL, 0 };
    Stack* st  = (Stack*) malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    st->top = NULL;
    return st;
}
```

and my `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "stack.h"

int main () {

    struct Stack* st = new_stack();

    return 0;

}
```

`gcc` throws these errors:

> make (in directory: /home/diego/temp/stack) gcc -g -O2 -std=c99 -c
>
> main.c In file included from main.c:4: Compilation failed. stack.h:10:
>
> error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘StackNode’
>
> stack.h:14: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’
>
> before ‘*’ token main.c: In function ‘main’: main.c:8: warning:
>
> implicit declaration of function ‘new_stack’ main.c:8: warning:
>
> initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast make: ***
>
> [main.o] Error 1

**EDIT**: I found the error. I forgot to put `struct` before `Stack` and `StackNode` in some lines. Always having `struct` on those lines solves the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
struct Stack {
    StackNode* top;
};
```

to:

```
struct Stack {
    struct StackNode* top;
};
```

and anywhere else `StackNode` or `Stack` is used and not preceded by `struct`. If you wish to not specify `struct` you could use a `typedef`.